Nextjs Application fails on vercel build with ReferenceError: self is not defined
intergrating highcharts library on a nextjs application for stock and crypto currency pair
but application fails when trying to build on vercel with referrence error self not defined response, initially integrated tradingview library now opting to highcharts
how can this be resolved?
below is the source code and error
    "use client"

import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'


import Chart from '@/components/chart'
import Navbar from '@/components/navbar'
import Rates from '@/components/rates'
import Amt from '@/components/amt'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import AuthValidator from '@/components/authValidator'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import Hero from '@/app/hero'
// import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { Urls } from '@/app/urls'
import { useRouter, } from 'next/navigation'
import Filter from '@/components/filter'
import { AuthencticationAction } from '@/reducer/reducer'
import FlipClockCountdown from '@leenguyen/react-flip-clock-countdown'
import '@leenguyen/react-flip-clock-countdown/dist/index.css';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'


import indicators from 'highcharts/indicators/indicators';

// const Highcharts = dynamic(() => import('highcharts/highstock'), {
//     ssr: false
// });

// const HighchartsReact = dynamic(() => import('highcharts-react-official'), {
//     ssr: false
// });




// HC_drag_panes(Highcharts)
// import Chart from '@/components/chart'



// const ChartContainer = dynamic(
//     () =>
//       import("@/components/chart").then((mod) => mod.Chart),
//     { ssr: false }
//   );


// require('highcharts/indicators/indicators')(Highcharts)


const url = Urls()
function Dashboard() {
    if (typeof Highcharts === "object") {
        indicators(Highcharts)
        require('highcharts/indicators/indicators')(Highcharts)
        require('highcharts/indicators/macd')(Highcharts)
        
        require('highcharts/indicators/price-channel')(Highcharts);  
      }
    // Load Highcharts modules



    const router = useRouter()
    const [graph, setGraph] = useState('candlestick')
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [expiry, setExpiry] = useState(null)
    const [TestchartData, setchartData] = useState({})
    const authData = useSelector(state => state.reducer.authreducer)
    const logged_in = authData.logged_in

    const chartData = useSelector(state => state.reducer.chartreducer)
    const ChartContainer = useRef()
    let ticker_symbol = localStorage.getItem('ticker_data')

    console.log('chartData', chartData)




    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log(this)


    }, [])


    const getSubscriptionData = () => {
        fetch(`${url.subscription_data}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${authData.accessToken}`
            },
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('subscription_Data', data.data[0])
                setExpiry(data.data[0].end_date)
                // dispatch(AuthencticationAction.Login({...authData,'expiry':data.data[0].end_date}))
            })
    }

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        getSubscriptionData()

    }, [])

    const handleGraphChange = e => {
        setGraph(e.target.value)
    }

    const fetchHighchartData = async () => {
        setchartData({
            data: [],
            data_volume: [],
            show_data: false
        })
        const data = await fetch(
            'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlcv.json'
        ).then(response => response.json());
        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        const ohlc = []
        const volume = []
        const dataLength = data.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
            ohlc.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][1], // open
                data[i][2], // high
                data[i][3], // low
                data[i][4] // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][5] // the volume
            ]);
        }
        setchartData({
            data: ohlc,
            data_volume: volume,
            show_data: true
        })

        console.log(this)
    }



    useLayoutEffect(() => {

        fetchHighchartData()

        const handleResize = () => {
            console.log(ChartContainer.current.chart.reflow())
            if (ChartContainer.current) {
                ChartContainer.current.chart.reflow();
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);


    }, [])

    const options = {
        chart: {
            height: '600',
            // backgroundColor: 'transparent', // Change background color of the chart
            color: 'white',
            padding: '20',
        },

        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }]
        },


        title: {
            text: 'My chart',

        },

        yAxis: [{
            height: '75%',
            width: '100%',
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3

            },
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            }
        }, {
            top: '75%',
            height: '25%',
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            offset: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'MACD'
            }
        }],



        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            id: 'aapl',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: TestchartData.data,

        },
        {
            type: 'pc',
            id: 'overlay',
            linkedTo: 'aapl',
            yAxis: 0,
            data: TestchartData.data_volume,
            name: "adx"
        },
        // {
        //     type: "column",
        //     name: 'volume',
        //     linkedTo: 'aapl',
        //     id: 'volume',
        //     yAxis: 1,
        //     data: TestchartData.data_volume,

        // },

        {
            type: "macd",
            name: 'Volume',

            linkedTo: 'aapl',
            id: 'oscillator',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: TestchartData.data_volume,

        }
        ],
        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [
                {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1mo',
                    events: {
                        click: function (obj) {
                            console.log(this)
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 3,
                    text: '3mo',
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            // console.log(this)
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        plotOptions: {
            candlestick: {
                color: '#A03C3C', // Color for bearish candles
                upColor: '#338546', // Color for bullish candles
                lineColor: '#000000', // Border color for candlesticks
                upLineColor: '#000000', // Border color for bullish candlesticks
            },
        },


    }
    // console.log(options)




    const fetchOscillatorData = (chart) => {
        const series = chart.get('overlay');
        console.log(series)
    }








    // useLayoutEffect(() => {

    //     if (!logged_in) {
    //         redirect('/auth')
    //     }

    // }, [])


    useEffect(() => {

    }, [])



    return (
        <>
            {/* {authData.logged_in ? */}
            <Hero>
                <main className={'bg-[#0B1215] lg:w-[100%] lg:h-[120vh]  max-xl:h-[100vh] lg:overflow-x-hidden md:h-[150vh] md:w-[100%] max-md:h-[100vh] max-md:w-[100%] '}>

                    <div className={'flex lg:w-full lg:h-[100%] md:h-full lg:flex-row p-2'}>
                        <aside className={' lg:flex lg:w-[25%] lg:h-[full] md:h-full p-5 md:hidden sm:hidden max-sm:hidden'}>
                            <Rates handleGraphChange={handleGraphChange} />
                        </aside>

                        <div className={'flex lg:flex-row p-0 lg:w-[100%] lg:h-full md:w-[100%] md:h-[100%] sm:w-[100%] sm:h-[100%] max-sm:w-[100%] max-sm:h-[100%]  border-white bg-[#101720] max-md:flex-col max-xl:flex-col md:flex-col'}>
                            <div className='flex flex-col w-[100%] h-[100%] p-2'>

                                <div className='p-0 m-0 w-[100%] lg:h-[10%] flex justify-center items-center'>
                                    <FlipClockCountdown

                                        // to={new Date(expiry).getTime() + 24 * 3600 * 1000 + 5000}
                                        to={'2024-09-12'}
                                        className='h-full' title='Count-Down'
                                        labels={['DAYS', 'HOURS', 'MINUTES', 'SECONDS']}

                                        digitBlockStyle={{ height: 45, width: 25, backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'bg-[#0B1215]' }}
                                        // dividerStyle={{ color: 'white', height: 1 }}
                                        //  separatorStyle={{ color: 'red', size: '6px' }}
                                        labelStyle={{ fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 500, textTransform: 'uppercase', color: 'white', marginTop: '10%' }}
                                    />;

                                </div>


                                {/* 
                                    <div className='w-[100%] lg:h-[20%] md:h-[40%] sm:h-[50%] max-sm:h-[70%] p-2 grid lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-2 max-sm:grid-cols-2  place-items-center' >
                                        <Filter />
                                    </div> */}
                                <div className='p-0 flex overflow-y-hidden justify-center items-center lg:w-[100%] lg:h-[90%] max-lg:w-[100%] max-lg:h-[70%] md:w-[100%] md:h-[70%] max-md:h-[100%] sm:w-[100%] sm:h-[100%] max-sm:w-[100%] max-sm:h-[100%]  '>

                                    {TestchartData.show_data ?

                                        <HighchartsReact
                                            highcharts={Highcharts}
                                            options={options}
                                            constructorType={'stockChart'}
                                            containerProps={{ style: { width: "100%" } }}
                                            ref={ChartContainer}

                                        />

                                        :
                                        <span className="loading loading-bars text-white loading-lg"></span>


                                    }


                                </div>
                            </div>




                        </div>

                    </div>

                </main>
            </Hero>

            {/* :
                router.push('/')

            } */}



        </>
    )
}

export default Dashboard



The "ReferenceError: self is not defined" error in Next.js typically pops up when a library or script is trying to access the window or self object during server-side rendering. Since window and self are only available in the browser, you need to ensure that the code accessing them is executed only on the client side (in the browser).

@DominikChudy  cause i used dynamic import but the chart failed to display what other possible means?
also on the error which library to be specific?

If you've tried dynamic import and chart still fails to load I strongly suggest to simplify the issue as much as possible and try to load the simplest possible chart to the simplest possible page. Then try to add some more advanced options.
